# Maven update policy snapshots with regards to local and remote snapshots

Tags: maven

I would just like to understand definitely the behaviour of the snapshot functionality in maven if your local and remote snapshots differ. For instance, say I had project A, and project B were B depends on A, and I am changing both A and B locally. But also other developers are changing B and deploying the project to the repository where the artefacts are hosted.

How can I ensure that if I am changing B locally, that project A will be using the local B, instead of remote B, even if my local B is older than the remote B? So basically I want to ensure that if I have made any local changes to a dependency project, I want any projects which have the modified project as a dependency to use the local modified version rather than the remote version.

How can I do this? Is there an updatePolicy which does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While building with snapshots, Maven will compare the local POM’s timestamp  to the remote.

You can control using the **updatePolicy** with value **never** , Maven will never try to retrieve another version. It will do that only if it doesn't exist locally

You need to set it in maven `Settings.xml` as follows

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>exampleSnapshots</id>
          <name>example Snapshots</name>
          <url>http://example.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
               ......
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
```

other options are `always`, `daily` (default), `interval:X` (where X is an integer in minutes).

Find more information in [maven Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: But is there a way that if I haven't updated my local version, that it will fetch the remote version for this case? I want it that if I have changed a project locally I will get the local version, if not I want the most updated remote version.

Comment: Maven update check will happen based on POM’s timestamp, when you build locally (even with out local changes ) it will update POM timestamp, so it will consider it as the latest